# Can't locate / interact with button on Instargram via. selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, instagram

I was trying to create a simple python program using selenium that needs to find and click the follow button.

This is the HTML Code:

```
<div class="             qF0y9          Igw0E   rBNOH          YBx95   ybXk5    _4EzTm                      soMvl                                                                                        " id="f2d16737c928a4">

<button class="sqdOP  L3NKy   y3zKF     " type="button">Abonnieren</button>
</div>
```

My python code:

```
example = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@class,'sqdOP  L3NKy   y3zKF     ')]")
example.click
```

Every time I try it just gives me: "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element"

If you want to take a look at the site you need to log in and go to the suggestions page where Instagram suggests people you should follow: https://www.instagram.com/explore/people/

Comment: Is this button you are trying to click the follow button?

Comment: @Luke Hamilton Yes

Comment: Let me know your thoughts on my answer! Happy to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[.='Abonnieren']").click()
```

Just look for the button with that text and click it.

Answer (score 0):

The XPATH you shared seems to be a **randomized string and will not be easily iterated** across other follow buttons. I would recommend grabbing the "full XPATH" via the HTML page that way you can have an loop-able action. See below code for a loop of clicking the follow button:

```
count=1
while True:
      try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/section/main/div/div[2]/div/div/div["+str(count)+")]/div[3]/button").click()
            count=count+1
      except:
            break
```